# How much significance did JKR put into the birth dates in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter

We know JK Rowling gave Harry Potter her own birth date for (presumably) purely sentimental reasons.
She has, I think, been remarkably detailed on the dates of birth for a huge number of her characters.
Significance is lent to their names, their wand properties and their Hogwarts houses, and so the birthdays don't seem to be discussed often.
Is there any evidence that suggests that Rowling used star signs or any other such ideas to lend meaning when she detailed the dates of birth for so very many of her characters?

Comment: In the case of Sirius Black, [she made up his birth date offhandedly to bribe fans](http://www.themarysue.com/sirius-blacks-birthday/).

Comment: @Rand al'Thor - I think she gave it away to bribe fans; it doesn't say she made it up then and there.

Answer (score 5):

Certainly many characters have *meaningful* birthdays, chosen through a variety of methods.

For example, J.K. Rowling [chose](https://web.archive.org/web/20090213131415/http://jkrowling.com/textonly/en/extrastuff_view.cfm?id=7) for Fred and George to have been born on April 1, due to their penchant for pranks and humor:

> Fred and George were born - when else? - on April Fool's Day.

Luna Lovegood, on the other hand, [was](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/622008983000363008) born on [Friday the 13th](http://takemeback.to/13-February-1981#.V3eHTLgrJEY):

[image]

---

I am not aware of Rowling (to date) admitting to having considered astrological signs when creating her characters. However, I suspect she may have, at least in a few cases. Attempts to correlate characters' personalities with their signs are beset with the same flaws that hinder real-life astrology, but some *other* associations are a bit too pat:

- Harry's sign is Leo, the Lion. The lion, of course, is the symbol of Gryffindor house. Since Harry shares Rowling's birthday, this must have come later, but I still wonder whether it is a coincidence. Perhaps Rowling chose the house symbol for this reason. In particular, we know five Leos (Harry, Percy Weasley, Ginny Weasley, Celestina Warbeck, and Neville Longbottom) and all are Gryffindors.
- Luna Lovegood, basically a hippy, was born under Aquarius.

Comment: I'd forgotten that Fred and George were born on April Fool's Day - just the sort of significance other than star signs I was thinking of. Are there any others like this? For example, I seem to remember Voldemort was born on New Year's Eve - but what does that mean?

Comment: @ThruGog - Well, to start with, it means that he and Harry are seven months apart. And seven is the most powerful magical number.

Comment: Astrology FTW! :-D